# how to delete firebase auth google ID delete

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, oauth, firebase-authentication

I'm using below code for delete account in android, however, they restrict to re auth when auth time is exceed.
How can I re auth in case of google oauth and other oauth company?

```
Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the documentation on [re-authenticating the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user), you will need to recreate the `Credentials` with which the user was originally signed in and then call `user.reauthenticate(credential)` with those credentials.

For a user signed in with Google, recreating the credentials is done the same was as you originally got them, as shown in the documentation on [signing in with Google Play Games](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/play-games#authenticate_with_firebase) and this [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/8184cba2c40842a180f91dcfb4a216e721cc6ae6/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L104-L106) with something like this:

```
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
```

Comment: I tried this before, however, I hope to know how can I get idToken. And I'm using it kotlin.

Comment: I linked the code where this comes from, precisely so that you can check where all the values come from? If you tried this before and couldn't get it to work, that would be useful to include in your question going forward.